# Specflow scenario outline examples table - to object?

Tags: specflow

I am using specflow and I have a rather large table in my examples:

it has around 14 fields.

is there a better way of passing all of those filds into a method that is item1 and item2 and item4

I can see that there is a create set method, but this doesn't seem to cater for examples, and only in step....well steps.

is there a way to pass the data in an object rather than sending 14 strings?

Hope that makes sense.

Ta,

Steve

** Edit ** adding an example
Here is the headers for my exmaple file
`| propLocation | locPropToBuy | propertyType               | newBuild | appsLiveProprty | ownershipType | purchPrice | totLoanAmount | intOnlyAmount | prefLoanTermYrs | prefLoanTermMths |`

the method generated for this will look like this:

`[When(@"the user provides input for the Property and Loan Requirements Section (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*) and (.*)")]
        public void WhenTheUserProvidesInputForThePropertyAndLoanRequirementsSectionEnglandAndYesAndTerracedHouseAndYesAndYesAndStandardAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndSAnd(string propLocation, 
            string locPropToBuy, string propertyType, string newBuild, string legalOwnership, 
            string ownershipType, string equityShreScheme, string purchPrice, string fullMarketVal, 
            string termShareLoanYrs, string termShareLoanMths, string totLoanAmount, 
            string intOnlyAmount, string prefLoanTermYrs, string prefLoanTermMths)`

Although I will eventually change the coded values to (.*) etc.

It would be easier for me if I could just pass an object or a list of all the values rather than long instances of strings.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your steps, tables, examples and bindings? I am not sure what do you mean. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated it a bit. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Specflow tables

```
When the user provides input for the Property and Loan Requirements Section
| Key         | Value      |
| propLocation| NYC        |
| locPropToBuy| House123   |
| propertyType| House      |
| newBuild    | Nope       |
```

and so on and so on

Create a new class with PropertyLoanData and then interpret the table

```
    public class PropertyLoanData
    {
      public string propLocation { get; set; }
      public string locPropToBuy { get; set; }
      public string propertyType { get; set; }
      public string newBuild     { get; set; }
    }
```

.

```
   [When(@"the user provides input for the Property and Loan Requirements Section
    public void WhenUserprovidesinputforPropertyAndLoanSection(Table table)
    {
        var proploandata = table.CreateInstance<PropertyLoanData>();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("propLocation")).SendKeys(proploandata.propLocation);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("locPropToBuy")).SendKeys(proploandata.locPropToBuy);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("propertyType")).SendKeys(proploandata.propertyType);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("newBuild")).SendKeys(proploandata.newBuild);
    }
```